# Kafka sink record to binary

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to write kafka sink record into a binary file using java 8. Does anyone have the solution in java?

this is my code.I am not sure if this is how it should be done.Can anyone suggest?

```
public void write(SinkRecord record) throws IOException {
    byte [] values = record.value().toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
    printStream.print(values);
    printStream.print("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ByteArrayConverter`, then `record.value()` will already be Bytes, so you don't need to `toString()` it...

It's not clear what `printStream` does, but note: Kafka Connect is meant to be distributed in a cluster, so you would only be writing to a local file *on each worker*. Better if you use existing HDFS/S3 sink connectors - S3 Sink [already supports storing Raw Bytes](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/s3-sink/current/overview.html#s3-object-formats)

**Any** file is already "binary". If you want to be able to *read* those files back out in any reasonable format, I would suggest using Avro, for example, and it would store each record in `bytes` Avro schema. Or otherwise, you could use line-delimited Base64 encoded values in a plain text file.

A database table like this might work as well, if you want to use JDBC Sink connector instead

```
topic VARCHAR(255)
partition INT
offset INT
data BLOB
```

Comment: printstream is used to write sink record.I am trying to transform the sink record into a pojo format and after that I will convert it into binary file by converting each field value into bytes like codec implementation.So I was looking for any sample code available.

Comment: There is no sample code because what you're doing is not common or recommended. Don't use POJO. Use Avro files, as mentioned. Keep data cross-platform, not tied to Java models. Or, also mentioned, use ByteArrayConverter in your Connector config. Use ByteArrayOutputStream, not Printstream to write data to a buffer/file. Also mentioned, don't write to local filesystem unless you have a plan of collecting files across multiple Connect workers.